# Controller should not reload on $location.path()

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

Is there anyway to change a url without reloading the controller, I am using angular ui-router and my url Structure is like ***/:param1/data/:param2*** on some button click i am changing the url to ***demo1/data/demo2*** to ***demo3/data/demo4*** using **$location.path('demo3/data/demo4')**, this reloads the controller and hence the state is also lost. I just want to change the url without reloading the controller.

Answer (score 1):

Try using $state.go() like this:

```
$state.go('currentStateName', {param1: 'demo3', param2: 'demo4'})
```

I couldn't verify, but it should not reload if the state stays the same.

For further reading check out TransitionOptions ([1](https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/docs/latest/interfaces/transition.transitionoptions.html)). A third optional argument for $state.go(). It contains an option 'reload', which is false by default.

[[1]: https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/docs/latest/interfaces/transition.transitionoptions.html#reload](https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/docs/latest/interfaces/transition.transitionoptions.html)